# SASS: Can't Share Variables Between Files

Tags: css, sass

I've got a file called `app.scss`, inside that file I'm making four `@import`s:

```
@import "settings";
@import "foundation";
@import "type";
@import "custom";
```

I'm defining a `$main-color` variable like this in `settings.scss`:

```
$main-color: blue;
```

But for some reason when I reference that file in `custom.scss`, I get an error:

```
body {
    background-color: $main-color;
}
```

Any idea what might be causing this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you importing `settings` in your `custom` file?

Answer (score 1):

You should rename settings.scss/custom.scss to _settings.scss/_custom.scss.